# Diferencias de uso entre los adjetivos "corporal" y "corpóreo"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, adjetivos, diferencias-entre-palabras

Me refiero a las siguientes acepciones de estos dos adjetivos, según el DLE:

> [**corporal**](https://dle.rae.es/corporal?m=form)
>
> 1. adj. Perteneciente o relativo al cuerpo, especialmente al humano. *Presencia corporal*. *Pena corporal*.

> [**corpóreo**](https://dle.rae.es/corp%C3%B3reo?m=form)
>
> 1. adj. Que tiene cuerpo o consistencia.
> 2. adj. Perteneciente o relativo al cuerpo o a su condición de tal.

Por ejemplo, hablando de la *Divina Comedia* de Dante Alighieri, una persona mencionó que, en el Infierno y en el Purgatorio, las almas tienen una forma **corpórea** y sufren una pena **corporal**. Esta persona aseguraba que, en este ejemplo, no se puede decir "forma corporal", cosa que puedo entender, porque se debe utilizar "corpórea" en la acepción 1, y tampoco se puede utilizar "pena corpórea". Esta última afirmación me causa duda porque, según las definiciones del diccionario, tanto "corporal" como "corpóreo" pueden tener el significado de "perteneciente o relativo al cuerpo", con lo cual a mí me da la sensación que también se debería poder decir "pena corpórea". Pero puede que sea así debido a diferencias de uso entre estos dos adjetivos. ¿Alguien sabría explicar estas diferencias?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A mi entender, la sutil diferencia entre "corpóreo" y "corporal" puede deducirse más fácilmente a través de sus combinaciones léxicas.

Mientras "corpóreo" se contrapone a "etéreo" o "espiritual" (concreto vs. abstracto), "corporal" está más relacionado con "físico" (vs. emocional/moral).

Así, "corpóreo" generalmente aparece junto a sustantivos como "forma" o "mundo" y en contextos filosóficos ([Ejemplos con CORPÓREO](https://es.yourdictionary.com/frases/corp%C3%B3reo)).

El adjetivo "corporal", mucho más común, puede predicarse de sustantivos como *daño, lesión, lenguaje, temperatura, posición, estructura, peso* ([Ejemplos con CORPORAL](https://es.yourdictionary.com/frases/corporal)).

Comment: Coincido con la respuesta. Me da que _corpóreo_ se usa de forma más etérea, poética a veces

Comment: Para quienes saben algo del inglés, un truco heurístico muy útil es que tanto "corporal" como "body" empleado como adjetivo suelen traducirse por "corporal", mientras que "corporeal" se traduce por "corpóre@". Corporal damage, corporal injury, body language, body temperature, body position, body structure, body weight, corporeal form, corporeal realm.

Comment: Aunque desafortunadamente "bodily" es ambiguo. Bodily fluids definitivamente son fluidos corporales, pero una bodily form es una forma corpórea.

Comment: Acabamos de ponerles a los peques el primer episodio de "Yokai watch", y aparece una especie de fantasma que se refiere a un niño como "mi corpóreo amigo", así que me parece muy correcta la respuesta.